# How to delete and return an edge in Age (Apache AGE) by matching its properties

Tags: database, graph-databases, apache-age

I am using Age (Apache AGE), a PostgreSQL extension for graph databases. I have a graph called sample_graph with Car and Country nodes, connected by MadeIn edges. Currently, my MadeIn edges do not have any properties. I want to delete a specific edge based on the properties of the edge itself and return the deleted edge.

Here's an example of the current state of my graph:

```
Car {name: 'Lamborghini', madeIn: 'Italian'} -[MadeIn]-> Country {name: 'Italian'}
Car {name: 'Ford', madeIn: 'America'} -[MadeIn]-> Country {name: 'America'}
Car {name: 'Bughatti', madeIn: 'French'} -[MadeIn]-> Country {name: 'French'}
```

I tried the following query, but it deletes the vertex instead of the edge:

```
SELECT *                                                         
FROM cypher('sample_graph', $$                                                     
MATCH (a:Car)-[r:MadeIn]->(b:Country)                                           
WHERE a.name = 'Lamborghini' AND b.name = 'Italy'                               
DELETE r                                                                        
RETURN r                                                                    
$$) as (r agtype);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/delete.html) you can use the similar command like following to delete an edge and return it filtered by some property:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n {name: 'Andres'})-[r:KNOWS]->()
    DELETE r
    RETURN r
$$) as (v agtype);
```

And there is also a typing mistake in the above query of yours where you wrote `Italy` rather then `Italian`

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your query :
`WHERE a.name = 'Lamborghini' AND b.name = 'Italy'`

According to the nodes in your database it should be `Italian` not `Italy`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to delete the relation between two vertices based on the properties of the edge:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('sample_graph', $$
    MATCH (Car {name: 'Lamborghini', madeIn: 'Italian'})-[r:MadeIn]->(Country {name: 'Italian'})
    DELETE r
    RETURN r
$$) as (r agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete an edge in a graph and return it filtered by a specific property, you can use the following command:

```
    SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n {name: 'Andres'})-[r:KNOWS]->()
    DELETE r
    RETURN r
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

In the given example, the query targets a graph named "graph_name." It looks for a node with the property "name" equal to 'Andres' and deletes the outgoing edges of type "KNOWS" from that node. The deleted edges are then returned as the result.

Also `b.name = 'Italy'` should be replaced with `b.name = 'Italian'`, as per data.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't delete the vertex, the query you are trying shouldn't do anything. Instead the following queries will work in those case.

For deleting vertex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
MATCH (Car {name: 'Lamborghini', madeIn: 'Italian'})
DELETE v
$$) as (v agtype);
```

For deleting all vertices and edges

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (Car {name: 'Lamborghini', madeIn: 'Italian'})
    DETACH DELETE v
$$) as (v agtype);
```

For deleting the edge only:

```
SELECT *                                                         
FROM cypher('sample_graph', $$                                                     
MATCH (a:Car)-[r:MadeIn]->(b:Country)                                           
WHERE a.name = 'Lamborghini' AND b.name = 'Italian'                               
DELETE r                                                                                                                                          
$$) as (r agtype);
```

For deleting and returning the edge:

```
SELECT *                                                         
FROM cypher('sample_graph', $$                                                     
MATCH (a:Car)-[r:MadeIn]->(b:Country)                                           
WHERE a.name = 'Lamborghini' AND b.name = 'Italian'                               
DELETE r                                                                        
RETURN r                                                                    
$$) as (r agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the `name` property for the `Country` node in your query. It should be `Italian` not `Italy`.
Hence the correct query should be:

```
SELECT *                                                         
FROM cypher('sample_graph', $$                                                     
MATCH (a:Car)-[r:MadeIn]->(b:Country)                                           
WHERE a.name = 'Lamborghini' AND b.name = 'Italian'                               
DELETE r                                                                        
RETURN r                                                                    
$$) as (r agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have made a typo in your query where you used 'Italy' instead of 'Italian' in the `WHERE` clause.
Your updated query would be;

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('sample_graph', $$
MATCH (a:Car {name: 'Lamborghini'})-[r:MadeIn]->(b:Country {name: 'Italian'}
DELETE r
RETURN r
$$) as (r agtype);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Apache AGE, you can delete and return an edge by matching its properties using the Cypher query language. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
MATCH (source:Label1)-[edge:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(target:Label2)
WHERE edge.property = 'property_value'
DELETE edge
RETURN source, target
```